# enum not able to understand in memory and functionality

Tags: c, memory, enums

I am not able to understand below code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
enum x_t{a,b,c,d};
main()
{
enum y{ x=3};
a=x;
printf("a=%d\n",a);
printf("x=%d\n",x);
printf("c=%d\n",c);
}
```

Points what I am not clear are:
1-why enum cant be assigned to other enum,are they constants?If they are not constants then can I assign a number to enum?
2-what is the need to assign a tag to enum when we can access directly a value without x_t,I knew it is for Identifier purpose in designs but is there going to be any memory assigned with this tag ,if so where is this getting allocated in Data segment?

Can I do this below code which is asked in first point.

```
#include<stdio.h>
enum x_t{a,b,c,d};
main()
{
a=3;
printf("a=%d\n",a);
printf("x=%d\n",x);
printf("c=%d\n",c);
}
```

Please help me in understanding the memory structure of enum ,why it is behaving as constant .
Error what I get is

> lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Comment: This question is really "What are enums?"  This is something you should get from a C tutorial, not a SO post.

Answer (score 1):

`enum`s are exactly that: literal constants. They're not variables that can change at all.

You would use an `enum` when you want to associate some identifiers with each other. The classic is the suits in a deck of cards:

```
enum Suits { Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades };
```

That means that throughout your code you can say `suit = Hearts;`, or compare them like `if (suit1<suit2)` or something. But `Hearts = Diamonds;` doesn't make sense.

As an implementation detail, `Clubs` would get the value `0`, and the next ones would get successive values. You can change this if you want:

```
enum Suits { Clubs=1, Diamonds/*=2*/, // Diamonds gets 2 anyway: it's the next value
             Hearts=4, Spades=8 };
```

With C and C++, though, if you were to output the value you'd get its numeric equivalent: not the string. To get that, you have to organise it yourself. Assuming the original definition:

```
enum Suits { Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades };
char suitSymbolA[] = { '\5', '\4', '\3', '\6' }; // ASCII version
wchar_t suitSymbolU[] = { L'♣', L'♦', L'♠', L'♠' }; // Unicode version
char *suitString[] = { "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades" };
```

Comment: `char suitSymbol` is not going to work unless you are using CP437 or something like that.

Comment: But I am looking to pass value to enum variable at run time in code , is it possible ?

Comment: what does CP437 mean

Comment: @harish CP437 is a particular character Code Page (there are lots). CP437 is the one used on the original IBM PC that had the standard ASCII characters, plus special graphics characters outside of the normal range.

Comment: @harish You can copy an enum variable to another of the same type with no problems. If you want to save it or load it, you'll need to convert it to/from an int with a cast: `int i = (int)suit; Suits suit = (Suits)i;`